# How to scroll single element in listview Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a listview, there are 5 elements in there and I can't scroll single element in the listview, how can I Do it?
An element scrolls only if I set container's height to 80px, but I need it 100px

```
SizedBox(                      
 new ListView(
      controller: _controller,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, bottom: 40),
      children: children,
    ).
);
```

Comment: what's the purpose of including the listview in a sized box? is this sizedbox included inside another listview ?

Comment: @Salma. no, I just wanted to check if it will help me,

Answer (score 0):

you can use slivers

```
 return Scaffold(
    body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverPadding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          sliver: SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
              [
                Card(child: Text('data'),),
                Card(child: Text('data'),),
                Card(child: Text('data'),),
                Card(child: Text('data'),),

                // Scrollable horizontal widget here
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```